# Unable to see entered text in the input field in IE11 browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I'm using clarity ui framework for building the website. I have added some additional padding on top of the clarity ui input field. It's seems working in all browsers except in IE11 where I'm unable to see the entered text. What changes do I have to make in order for the text to appear in the input field?

Here is the stackblitz link to get access to the code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-forms-test-ea75jb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

```
<div class="clr-control-container">
            <div class="clr-input-wrapper">
              <input type="text" id="example" placeholder="Example Input" class="clr-input">
            </div>
 </div>
```

**Styles**

```
input[type] {
   background-color: grey;
    padding: 21px 6px; //Adding padding is the reason causing the issue
   color:white;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
```

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Looks like your stackblitz example get hanged in IE browser. Did you got the same result when you directly try to access the site in IE browser? Is there any error or warning in console?

Comment: Yes I'm getting the same result and I'm not seeing any errors or warning in console.
https://clarity-forms-test-ea75jb.stackblitz.io . You can use this link to access the site instead of code

Answer (score 1):

I try to check the code using developer tools and and I find that **_ngcontent-c0** causing this issue.

[image]

If you remove it from the code than you can able to see the test in the text box in IE.

[image]

Comment: I am using angular framework and "_ngcontnet-c0" is auto generated by angular. I don't why its causing the issue only for ie11 and especially while using forms

Comment: Looks like "_ngcontnet-c0" is also applying style rules in IE so may be it conflict with your clarity ui style caused this issue in IE.